# Reflection of orthocenter about side midpoints is the diameter of circumcircle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

Let H be the orthocenter of ABC. Let Y the reflection over the midpoint of BC. Show that AY is a diameter of (ABC), the circunference that passes through ABC.

My take: Using the fact that HCYB is a parallelogram (since its diagonals cross in their respective midpoints), we can state that $\angle$BYC = $\angle$BHC which is 180º - $\angle$ BAC. Since $\angle$ BAC + $\angle$ BYC = 180º, ABYC  is a cyclic quadrilateral and Y lies on the circle. But I'm unsure on how to prove AY is a diameter, or that (which is equivalente) $\angle$ ACY = $\angle$ ABY = 90º. I know this question: [Reflection of orthocenter about side midpoints lies on circumcircle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132321/reflection-of-orthocenter-about-side-midpoints-lies-on-circumcircle) has an answer which solves this with the use of complex numbers, but I would prefer a geometric aproach if possible.

Problem taken from Euclidean Geometry in Matematical Olympiads, by Evo Chen.

Comment: Your title reads as if **both** points are symmetrical with respect to the midpoints which is not the case if I understand well.

Comment: @JeanMarie In fact, $X$ isn't needed (to understand the question), so you can ignore it.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thanks. Besides, we have exchanged one or 2 days ago about [this under-determined question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/578245) : I have written since a solution using the Cayley-Menger determinant.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Yes, really X is needed for another question in the same exercise. I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution doesn't use anything fancy.
These relationships can be observed if you drew the accurate diagram several times, which is a good first step for olympiad problems.
Fill in the details.

1. Show that $Y$ lies on the circumcircle (done in statement).
2. Let $X$ be the reflection of $H$ across $BC$. Show that $X$ also lies on the circumcircle by (similar) angle chasing.
3. Show that $XY \parallel BC$.
4. Show that $AHX$ is a straight line.
5. Since $AH \perp BC$, hence $\angle AXY = 90^ \circ$.
6. Hence $AY$ is the diameter of the circumcircle.

Comment: I originally came to the conclusion that $\angle AXY = 90º$ using similar triangles ($ADM$ and $AXY$, M being the midpoint of BC), but I made nothing of it, insisting on fiding the angles of $AYC$ and $AYB$. But of course X lies in the same circunference! Thanks for the proof!

Comment: @RicardoMM That's one example of why it's so important to share what you've worked out thus far. You could be really close to a solution, and just need a slight nudge. In the IMO, I've seen solutions waver from being awarded 2 or 5 based solely on the presentation / organization of information.

Comment: @CalvinLin - Can you give some hints on how to prove $XY \parallel BC $?

Comment: @Yassir It should be immediate. EG The perpendicular distance of points $X, B, Y$ to the line $BC$ are all the same, hence $XY \parallel BC$.

Answer (score 1):

This solution follows from the fact that $H$ is the center of homothety (expansion) from the nine-point circle to the circumcenter. (You don't need to know this fact to understand the solution. In fact, this solution establishes this fact.)
It's a natural way to set up the question, and possibly how it was set.

Let $D$ be the midpoint of $BC$.
Let $P$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $A$ to $BC$.
Let $T$ be the midpoint of $AH$.
Recall that $DPT$ are 3 points of the nine-point circle, whose center $N$ is the midpoint of $OH$. $DNT$ is a diameter of the circle (since $\angle DPT = 90^\circ$).

By considering triangle $AOH$, it follows that $TN \parallel AO$ by midpoints.
By considering triangle $HOY$, it follows that $ND \parallel OY$ by midpoints.
Since $TND$ is a straight line, hence $AOY$ is a straight line, so $AY$ is the diameter of the circumcircle (given that $Y$ lies on the circumcircle).